# Add a Legend to D3 Force Directed Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I am trying to create a legend in the bottom right corner of my D3. I have written all of the code for the legend but it comes up as just a black screen with the force-directed graph not showing up as well. Any advice would help.

**Legend Code:**

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["<400", "400-549", "550-699", "700-849", "850-999", "1000-1149", "1150-1299", "1300-1449", ">1450"])
    .range(["#1a9850", "#66bd63", "#a6d96a","#d9ef8b","#ffffbf","#fee08b","#fdae61","#f46d43","#d73027"]);


    var legend = d3.append('svg')
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize;
        var x = 0;
        var y = i * height;
        return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
    });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

**D3 Code:**

```
function start(){
var w = 1200,
    h = 600,
    radius = 10,
    node,
    link,
    root;

var count = 0;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["<400", "400-549", "550-699", "700-849", "850-999", "1000-1149", "1150-1299", "1300-1449", ">1450"])
    .range(["#1a9850", "#66bd63", "#a6d96a","#d9ef8b","#ffffbf","#fee08b","#fdae61","#f46d43","#d73027"]);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .on("tick", tick)
    .charge(function(d) { return -500; })
    .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 100 : 50; })
    .size([w, h - 160]);

    `
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);




svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#000");

    var legend = d3.append('svg')
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize;
        var x = 0;
        var y = i * height;
        return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
    });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });




root = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
console.log("root"+root);
root.fixed = true; 
root.x = w / 2;
root.y = h / 2 - 80;
update();




function update() {
    var nodes = root.nodes,
        links = root.links;

    // Restart the force layout.
    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();


    // Update the links…
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links);

    // Enter any new links.
    link.enter().insert("svg:line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    // Exit any old links.
    link.exit().remove();

    // Update the nodes…
      node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) {
                return d.name;
            })
            .style("fill", color);

    node.transition()
        .attr("r", radius);


    // Enter any new nodes.
    node.enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.image;})
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("r", function(d)
              {return d.size * 2 ;})
        .style("fill", color)
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);
    node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Exit any old nodes.
    node.exit().remove();


    title = svg.selectAll("text.title")    
         .data(nodes);

    // Enter any new titles.
    title.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "title");
        //.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    // Exit any old titles.
    title.exit().remove();
}

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    title.attr("transform", function(d){ return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
    if(d._children){
        return "#95a5a6";
    }else{
        switch(d.group) {
            case 'r': //adverb
                return "#e74c3c";
                break;
            case 'n': //noun
                return "#3498db";
                break;
            case 'v': //verb
                return "#2ecc71";
                break;
            case 's': //adjective
                return "#e78229";
                break;
            default:
                return "rgb(0, 238, 238)";
        }
    }
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
document.getElementById("image").src = d.image;
document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = "Username:"+d.name;
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "ID:" + d.id;
document.getElementById("friends").innerHTML = d.friend;
document.getElementById("nodeTitle").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = d.size;
//document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Friend Count:" + d.name;
//if (d._children)
//grabImage();
//document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = (d.image);

/*if (d.children) { 
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update();*/
}

function mouseover() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 16);
}


function mouseout() {
  d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 8);
}

// Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
function flatten(root) {
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) node.size = node.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + recurse(v); }, 0);
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
        return node.size;
    }

    root.size = recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}};

do{
var intervalID = window.setTimeout(start, 1000)
}
while(jsonObject!=""){
}
```

**I believe the error is in here somewhere:**

```
    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .on("tick", tick)
        .charge(function(d) { return -500; })
        .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.target._children ? 100 : 50; })
        .size([w, h - 160]);

        `
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);




svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#000");

    var legend = d3.append('svg')
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize;
        var x = 0;
        var y = i * height;
        return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
    });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

JSFIDDLE :

[jsfiddle.net/d1kp0qeL/1](http://jsfiddle.net/d1kp0qeL/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
var legend = d3.append('svg').append("g")
```

should have been (you should append, the g group which holds legend to the svg)

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
```

Comment: ReferenceError: legendRectSize is not defined

Comment: All I am getting is a blank screen now

Comment: it would be nice if you could make a working jsfiddle, its very difficult to help just by looking @ the code.

Comment: looked in the fiddle you forgot to define the jsonObject can you please set the value for that

Comment: Done https://jsfiddle.net/d1kp0qeL/2/                                                                                                       `jsonObject = {"request":"getTweetRelationshipGraphForUser", "screen_name" : "realDonaldTrump"}`