# Adding a legend to D3 graph V4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am currently trying to create a **legend** for my graph in D3 version 4. I've seen other examples where you can preset the legend with static text but I want for the legend labels to be loaded dynamically from the **csv** data which I am using. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class ="graphics"> </div>
```

Calling the graph with JS:

```
var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left:50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.channelA); });

    var valuelineTwo = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.channelB);});

    //apend the svg object o the body 
    var svg = d3.select(".graphics").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //GETtheDATA

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){
        if (error) throw error;

        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.channelA = + d.channelA;
            d.channelB = + d.channelB;
        });

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return Math.max(d.channelA, d.channelB);})]); 


         svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "FECB00")
        .attr("d", valueline);

         svg.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valuelineTwo);

        // Add the X Axis
      svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // Add the Y Axis
      svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));  
    });
```

Trying to create the Legend:

```
var legendRectSize = 18;                                 
var legendSpacing = 4;

var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     
          .data(color.domain())                                   
          .enter()                                                
          .append('g')                                            
          .attr('class', 'legend')                                
          .attr('transform', function(d, i) {                     
            var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;          
            var offset =  height * color.domain().length / 2;     
            var horz = -2 * legendRectSize;                       
            var vert = i * height - offset;                      
            return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')';        
          });                                                     

        legend.append('rect')                                     
          .attr('width', legendRectSize)                         
          .attr('height', legendRectSize)                         
          .style('fill', color)                                   
          .style('stroke', color);                                

        legend.append('text')                                     
          .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)              
          .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)              
          .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

I am also trying to draw a rectangle around the legend which I am not sure how to do and I cannot find any relevant examples:

Previous questions which I've checked: [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242812/add-legend-to-chart-with-d3-v4-angular-cli), [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615458/add-a-legend-to-d3-force-directed-graph), [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041565/dc-js-adding-a-legend-to-pie-chart)

Here is an image of how much graph looks: