# Adding a legend to D3 stacked bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've already read [Adding a legend to D3 graph V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831285/adding-a-legend-to-d3-graph-v4) and the questions linked within. Also, after a lot of searching... I'm surprised that D3 doesn't appear to have a standardized way of creating legends.

Here is my code:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xMonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month
     
var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year
      
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format('.2s'));

var formatNum = d3.format(",")
          
var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
   for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
})

data.forEach(function(d) {
  //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

var max = x.domain()[1];
var min = x.domain()[0];
var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
z.domain(keys);



    // the bars 
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
  
  //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
  var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + barWidth * 4.75;
  var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) - 30;
  var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col_1 and col_2 values
  
  //Update the tooltip position and value
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")      
    .select("#value")
    .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 
    
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")      
    .select("#month")
    .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the date
      
  //Show the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

   })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
  //Hide the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
  
  });

   
    // x-axis
    var monthAxis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xMonthAxis);
   
 
 const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
 xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));
   
 var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
      .call(xYearAxis);
      
 var sessionAxis = g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
     .call(yAxis);
   
  monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  pointer-events: none;
 }
 
 #tooltip.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 #tooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
 }
 
 rect:hover {
  fill:orange;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
 <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
 <p><strong>Value: </strong><span id="value"></span></p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to add a legend to this graph, and have tried a few options already, e.g.: http://bl.ocks.org/louking/6491d18c9cef56011971be76a85cde8e, http://d3-legend.susielu.com/, none of which seem to work well for my situation.

All I need in this legend is a rectangular box with a blue square with label `Column 2` and a rectangular box with a red square with label `Column 1`, with customizable positioning for the entire legend (i.e., I need to be able to control where the legend is placed).

Apparently React can do something like this as well... but I haven't had time to learn React yet.

Comment: *"I'm surprised that D3 doesn't appear to have a standardized way of creating legends"*. D3 doesn't have a standard way to create **anything**.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: I would suggest you look at [this](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/43f10523858abf6053ae) and/or [this](http://bl.ocks.org/juan-cb/ac731adaeadd3e855d26). These charts have very simple code for adding the legends and I think those will meet your requirements. Try them out and lets us know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following lines:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
```

as well as

```
var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }).reverse();
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                    .data(options.slice().filter(function(type){ return type != "total"}))
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legend")
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

    legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", z);

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return d;});
```

near the bottom. In addition, some CSS:

```
.legend {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 60%;
    }
```

```js
var dataAsCsv = `date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575`;


var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// parse the date / time
// look at the .csv in Notepad! DO NOT LOOK AT EXCEL!
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");


var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .range(["#CE1126", "#00B6D0"]); // red and blue 

var xMonthAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
              .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")); // label every month
     
var xYearAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
                  .ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
      .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")); // label every year
      
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format('.2s'));

var formatNum = d3.format(",")
          
var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv, function(d, i, columns) {
   for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
})

data.forEach(function(d) {
  //console.log(parseDate(d.date));
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
var barWidth = (width - margin.right- margin.left)/(data.length+1);     

data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });


x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );

var max = x.domain()[1];
var min = x.domain()[0];
var datePlusOneMonth = d3.timeDay.offset(d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1), -1); // last day of current month: move up one month, back one day 

x.domain([min,datePlusOneMonth]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
z.domain(keys);



    // the bars 
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class', function(d) { return d.key; })
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", barWidth)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
  
  //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
  var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[0]) + barWidth * 4.75;
  var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.mouse(this)[1]) - 30;
  var value = d.data[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class')]; // differentiating between col_1 and col_2 values
  
  //Update the tooltip position and value
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")      
    .select("#value")
    .text(formatNum(value)); // return the value 
    
  d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")      
    .select("#month")
    .text(d3.timeFormat("%B %Y")(d.data.date)); // return the date
      
  //Show the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

   })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
  //Hide the tooltip
  d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
  
  });

   
    // x-axis
    var monthAxis = g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xMonthAxis);
   
 
 const firstDataYear = x.domain()[0];
 xYearAxis.tickValues([firstDataYear].concat(x.ticks()));
   
 var yearAxis = g.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 25) + ")")
      .call(xYearAxis);
      
 var sessionAxis = g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
     .call(yAxis);
   
  monthAxis.selectAll("g").select("text")
   .attr("transform","translate(" + barWidth/2 + ",0)");
  
  var options = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }).reverse();
 var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
     .data(options.slice().filter(function(type){ return type != "total"}))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "legend")
     .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", z);
    
 function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
 }
    
 legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d;});
```

```css
#tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: auto;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      pointer-events: none;
     }
     
     #tooltip.hidden {
      display: none;
     }
     
     #tooltip p {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 20px;
     }
     
     rect:hover {
      fill:orange;
     }
      
.legend {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.7.0/d3-legend.min.js"></script>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
     <p><strong>Month: </strong><span id="month"></span><p>
     <p><strong>Value: </strong><span id="value"></span></p>
    </div>
```

The code creates a legend on the top right.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It turned out to be pretty easy, isn't it?

Comment: @Shashank Not nearly as bad as I thought it'd be. Your links helped a lot. Thanks. For some reason, I didn't see those examples when I was searching Google.

Comment: No problem! You've gotta improve your Google search queries haha (just being sarcastic). Have fun! :)